# Use defined variable in subclass for methods in base class

Tags: python, pytest

I have a base class and two different subclasses (they are in 3 different modules).
In the base class I have test methods which I use for the subclasses.
I want that the test methods in the base class to use the defined variables from the subclass. But I cannot access to the variables from the subclass, when I run the test methods in subclass.
Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

P.S.: I cannot use a `__init__` constructor (cannot collect test class)!

```
Error with __init__ contructor:   No tests found

============================== warnings summary =============================== src/test_icd_operation.py::TestICDFields   cannot collect test class
'TestICDFields' because it has a __init__ constructor

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
========================= 1 warnings in 16.80 seconds =========================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Code**:

```
class BaseClassExample:
  table_name = None

  def test_field_for_both_devices(self):
    firstname = get_field(table_name)



class SubClass1(BaseClassExample):
  table_name = 'Pacer'

  def test_field1():
    field1 = get_field(table_name)



class SubClass2(BaseClassExample):
  table_name = 'ICD'

  def test_field2(self):
    field2 = get_field(table_name)
```

So, when I run the tests in the class `SubClass1`, I want that variable `table_name` on the `BaseClassExample` to take the value `Pacer` from the variable in subclass `SubClass1`.

Comment: Could you add some of your code please ?
Can you show the error message ?

Comment: Base classes cannot use stuff defined in the sub classes.  Maybe you want to define the stuff in the base class and then just *override* it in the subclass?  Anyway, showing all of your code will definitely help in figuring this out.

Comment: I added an example @GwendalGrelier

Comment: Can you show the example please @alfe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.table_name`:

```python
class BaseClassExample:
  table_name = None

  def test_field_for_both_devices(self):
    firstname = get_field(self.table_name)



class SubClass1(BaseClassExample):
  table_name = 'Pacer'

  def test_field1():
    field1 = get_field(self.table_name)



class SubClass2(BaseClassExample):
  table_name = 'ICD'

  def test_field2(self):
    field2 = get_field(self.table_name)
```

Explanation: Python has a few [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) — global, local, class and instance. You cannot access `table_name` because Python looks it up in local and global namespaces and fails. You can access `self.table_name` because it's instance namespace which also has access to class namespace if the name is not shadowed in instance (in `self`).